# Sum of measure of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given $(X, \mathbb A, m)$ a measurable space and $\{E_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb A$ a sequence such that $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N} m (E_i) < + \infty$.

I want to show that $m$-almost every $x \in X$ is contained in at most finitely many of the $E_i$.

So, I rewrote the statement and know that I have to show that $\{i \in \mathbb N: x \in E_i\}$ is finite for $m$-almost every $x \in X$.

But does this not follow from the simple fact that $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N} m (E_i) < + \infty$ ?

Comment: What is the contrapositive of your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{E_i}(x)$. Now we have by assumptation (and monotone convergence theorem)
$$\int f(x) \, d \mu(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) < \infty.$$
Thus $f(x) < \infty$ for almost all $x \in X$. This only happens if for each $x \in X$ the sum is finite, i.e. $x$ is only contained in finite many of the $E_i$.

Comment: Hm is it possible to precise the last step a bit? Why "This only happens if..." is true?

Comment: $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{E_i}(x)$ can only be finite, if the sum is already finite. (If $1_{E_i}(x) =1$ for infinity many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the sequence $(\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{E_i}(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is unbounded and $f(x) = \infty$, because we sum 'infinite many $1$'.)